# Walk on tree with different actions on different nodes

Tags: java, object-oriented, tree

I have a tree whose nodes are of type `Node`. Depending on the type (one of the implementations of `Node`) nodes differ in the set of information that is stored in them (in the demo example, the information is not different). I also have action sets the `Action` that should be invoked when you visit a particular node type.

Although this is not implemented, I originally tried to write the code so that the action could support multiple types of nodes simultaneously.

```
public final class ActionA implements Action {
    @Override
    public void act(final NodeA node) {
        System.out.println("Act action1 (" + node.value() + ")");
    }

    @Override
    public void act(final NodeB node) {
        System.out.println("Act action1 (" + node.value() + ")");
    }
}
```

**Here's what I got actually**

I have a tree whose nodes are of type `Node`:

```
import java.util.List;

public interface Node {
    String value();
    List<Node> childs();
}
```

I have two implementations of `Node`:

```
public final class NodeType1 implements Node {

    private final String value;
    private final List<Node> childs;

    public NodeType1(String value, List<Node> childs) {
        this.value = value;
        this.childs = childs;
    }

    @Override
    public String value() {
        return this.value;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Node> childs() {
        return this.childs;
    }
}

public final class NodeType2 implements Node {

    private final String value;
    private final List<Node> childs;

    public NodeType2(String value, List<Node> childs) {
        this.value = value;
        this.childs = childs;
    }

    @Override
    public String value() {
        return this.value;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Node> childs() {
        return this.childs;
    }
}
```

I have `Action` interface and two implementation:

```
public interface Action {
    void act(Node node);
}

public final class Action1 implements Action {
    @Override
    public void act(final Node node) {
        System.out.println("Act action1 (" + node.value() + ")");
    }
}

public final class Action2 implements Action {
    @Override
    public void act(final Node node) {
        System.out.println("Act action2 (" + node.value() + ")");
    }
}
```

I also created `ActionSet` class for group actions

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class ActionSet {

    private List<Action> actions = new LinkedList<>();

    public ActionSet(final List<Action> actions) {
        this.actions = actions;
    }

    public boolean add(final Action action) {
        return actions.add(action);
    }

    public void act(final Node node) {
        for (final Action action : this.actions) {
            action.act(node);
        }
    }
}
```

This is `ActionSet1` and `ActionSet2`:

```
public final class ActionSet1 extends ActionSet {
    public ActionSet1() {
        super(new LinkedList<Action>() {{
            add(new Action1());
        }});
    }
}

public final class ActionSet2 extends ActionSet {
    public ActionSet2() {
        super(new LinkedList<Action>() {{
            add(new Action2());
        }});
    }
}
```

And I created `TreeWalker` class:

```
public final class TreeWalker {

    public void walk(final Node root) {
        if (root instanceof NodeType1) {
            walk((NodeType1) root);
        } else if (root instanceof NodeType2) {
            walk((NodeType2) root);
        }
    }

    public void walk(final NodeType1 root) {
        new ActionSet1().act(root);

        for (final Node child : root.childs()) {
            walk(child);
        }
    }

    public void walk(final NodeType2 root) {
        new ActionSet2().act(root);

        for (final Node child : root.childs()) {
            walk(child);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally this is my main `Application` class:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public final class Application {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Node tree = new NodeType2("hello", new LinkedList<Node>() {{
            add(new NodeType1("world", new LinkedList<Node>()));
            add(new NodeType2("bold", new LinkedList<Node>()));
        }});

        final TreeWalker walker = new TreeWalker();
        walker.walk(tree);
    }
}
```

If you execute this application you can see:

```
Act action2 (hello)
Act action1 (world)
Act action2 (bold)
```

How do you evaluate this design? What problems can it cause and what can be improved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Visitor pattern can be written as:

```
class Node {

    protected final Node[] childs;

    public Node() {
        this(new Node[] {});
    }

    public Node(final Node[] childs) {
        this.childs = childs;
    }

    public Node[] childs() {
        return this.childs;
    }

    public void accept(final Action visitor) {
        for (final Node child : childs()) {
            child.accept(visitor);
        }
        visitor.act(this);
    }
}

interface Action {
    default void act(final Node node) {
        if (node instanceof NodeA) {
            this.act((NodeA) node);
        } else if (node instanceof NodeB) {
            this.act((NodeB) node);
        }
        else if (node instanceof NodeC) {
            this.act((NodeC) node);
        } else if (node instanceof NodeD) {
            this.act((NodeD) node);
        }
    }
    default void act(final NodeB node) {}
    default void act(final NodeA node) {}
    default void act(final NodeC node) {}
    default void act(final NodeD node) {}
}

class NodeA extends Node {
    public NodeA(final Node[] elements) {
        super(elements);
    }
}

class NodeB extends Node {}
class NodeC extends Node {}
class NodeD extends Node {}

class ActionA implements Action {

    @Override
    public void act(final NodeB node) {
        System.out.println("Action A / Node B");
    }

    @Override
    public void act(final NodeA node) {
        System.out.println("Action A / Node A");
    }
}

class ActionB implements Action {

    @Override
    public void act(final NodeC node) {
        System.out.println("Action B / Node C");
    }

    @Override
    public void act(final NodeD node) {
        System.out.println("Action B / Node D");
    }
}

public class ApplicationDemo {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Node node = new NodeA(new Node[]{
                new NodeB(), new NodeD(),
                new NodeB(), new NodeC()
        });

        node.accept(new ActionB());
        node.accept(new ActionA());
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Action B / Node D
Action B / Node C
Action A / Node B
Action A / Node B
Action A / Node A
```